# How to get the different plan prices according to house income from the finder api

Tags: api, healthcare-finder-api, income

How to get the different plan prices according to house hold income from the finder api

looks like I could not find an field name "HouseHold" in the schema.

https://finder.healthcare.gov/api/finder_api_v3.0.xsd